# ##[warning]No coverage data found. Check the build errors/warnings for more details. Azure DevOps - SBT - Jacoco

Tags: azure-devops, sbt, azure-pipelines, code-coverage, jacoco

I am using [sbt-jacoco](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-jacoco/) to calculate code coverage and would like to publish Jacoco test coverage results in Azure DevOps test reports.

Here are my tasks:

```
  - script: "sbt jacoco"
    displayName: Run Jacoco

  - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
    displayName: Publish code coverage report
    inputs:
      codeCoverageTool: 'JaCoCo'
      summaryFileLocation: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/target/scala-2.13/jacoco/report/html/index.html
      reportDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/target/scala-2.13/jacoco/report
```

These tasks are executed successfully and the results are shared as an artifact on the pipeline. However, it also throws a warning which is

> ##[warning]No coverage data found. Check the build errors/warnings for more details.

I would like to see the results in a chart which is attached to the pipeline. Could you please help with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I needed to adjust the configuration settings following way.

```
 lazy val jacoco = jacocoReportSettings in Test := JacocoReportSettings(
      "Jacoco Coverage Report",
      None,
      JacocoThresholds(instruction = 10, method = 10, branch = 10, complexity = 10, line = 10, clazz = 10),
      Seq(JacocoReportFormats.ScalaHTML, JacocoReportFormats.XML),
      "utf-8"
    )

  override def projectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = super.projectSettings ++ jacocoSettings
```

and in Azure Pipelines it would be;

```
  - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
    inputs:
      codeCoverageTool: 'JaCoCo'
      summaryFileLocation: $(jacocoReportDir)/report/jacoco.xml
      reportDirectory: $(jacocoReportDir)/report/html
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your 'summaryFileLocation' property is pointing to the 'html' version of the report while (as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results?view=azure-devops)) it should point to the 'xml' version of it